# Lambda: Create a Lambda Function to Start EC2 / Join ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, amazon-cloudwatch

I have written a Lambda function via Python 2.7 (using boto3) to Start an EC2 Instance and then Join the EC2 instance to a standing ELB (for simple failover).

When the lambda goes off, it starts the EC2, but doesn't join the EC2 to the ELB.

Guidance?

1. How to non-hardcode the InstanceID and ELBID/
2. Why does it not work?

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   import boto3

   #True - Do nothing False - screw it all up
   debugMode = False

   #Declare


   #Instance Status
   #Hard Code InstanceIDs to script
   if debugMode == False:
       def lambda_handler(event, context):
   client = boto3.client('ec2')
   response = client.start_instances(InstanceIds=['i-someid',],
                      DryRun=False)
   print ('[SPACE]:')

   #Attach Instances to ELB once started.
   #Hardcode Instance
   def lamdba_hander(event, context):
   client = boto3.client('elb')
   response = client.register_instances_with_load_balancer(LoadBalancerName='someelb', Instances=[{'InstanceID': 'i-someid'},])
   print('[SPACE]:')
   ```

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done? What error messages are logged? What did AWS support say about this?

Comment: Off the cuff, perhaps it's trying to register the instance before it's ready to be registered. Try adding a 30-second pause between creating the instance and registering it.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Comment: Also, how do you variablize the instanceID and elb-ID , still green at Python.

Comment: This question is really more of a software dev question, and is more on-topic at SO. I'll migrate it over there.

Comment: So adding a time.sleep does not improve the state of which the EC2 instance joins the ELB. It does start the EC2 properly, yet my lambda does not force the EC2 into the ELB.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are passing the instance ID into the `register_instances_with_load_balancer` call.

Comment: It is there @MarkB after a long space.

Comment: response = client.register_instances_with_load_balancer(LoadBalancerName='someelb',Instances=[{'InstanceID': 'i-someid'},])

Comment: Do you get any error in the lamba execution?

Comment: I just took out the actual instanceID for discussion purposes.

Comment: No errors in Lambda Execution, no.